# Excel SUMIF using multiple ranges with OR?

Tags: excel

I am stumped over what probably is a simple task, but I just cannot get it to work.

I am trying to use a SUMIF formula to sum a range (C1:C6) based on whether one of two criterion ranges (A1:A6 and B1:B6) does not equal zero. In other words, I want it to sum the value in C if either A or B do not equal zero for a given row.

```
=SUMIF(A1:A6 OR B1:B6, "<>0", C1:C6)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUM(C1:C6)-SUMIFS(C1:C6,A1:A6,"=0",B1:B6,"=0")
```

This sums the entire then subtracts where both are 0, thus summing any that have at least one that does not equal 0.

Comment: Brilliant! I will mark this as the answer in 9 minutes. I really appreciate the help!